# Thinking of two elements as "the same"

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery elements, `$link = $('<a>')` and `$input = $('<input/>')`.

Although they are two different types of elements, they are in my code (and in my mind!) very linked:

1) Conceptually, they are different representations of one object.

2) They share the same attributes.

3) When one is displayed on the screen, the other is hidden.

Until now, I have used `.data()` to perform a link between the two:

```
$link.data('$input', $input);
$input.data('$link', $link);
```

As my code became more and more complex, this solution has proved confusing and messy.

Is there a different approach I may want to consider? For example, is there a way to keep the attributes of the two elements continually synced? Is there a way to make one "meta-object" out of the two? etc.

Comment: If an `a` is a representation of the same "object" as `input`, then you are abusing HTML horribly.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I imagine something like a form field displaying a value that you can click on to edit.

Comment: @Both: Please see http://wikilearner.net/wiki for an idea of what I am doing. If you have clever suggestions, I'm all ears! (You can drag-and-drop links, or type in the links.)

Comment: @Randomblue: Right-click, "view source".

Comment: @Tomalak: Are you saying "Warning! We can see your source!" or "Please, could I see your source?" ?

Comment: @Randomblue: I'm saying "look at the source" and find out how it's done.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's **my** website! I created the source, and I know how it's done. But according to you it's a "horrible HTML abuse", so I'm trying to change my approach.

Comment: @Randomblue: Oh, I'm with you. Nice GUI! In hindsight, and now that I know what you _really_ mean by "object", perhaps it's not so abusive after all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `.add()`

```
$link = $('<a>');
$input = $('<input />');
$both = $link.add($input);
$both.doStuff(); //Will apply to both
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question.

Comment: It's a start, actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Using IDs

Each of those elements should have a proper `id` attribute.

You can use the IDs to lookup other elements.

#### Example

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="obj-1-a">Link</a>
<input id="obj-1-input" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('input#' + this.id.replace(/a/, 'input')).show();
    $(this).hide();
});

$('input').click(function() {
    $('a#' + this.id.replace(/input/, 'a')).show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/USEyR/)

---

### Using structure

Alternatively, you may use simple structuring to group your elements.

This has the advantage that you do not need to provide an `id` attribute for each of your DOM elements, but it may restrict you in terms of *where* you can place your elements within the DOM tree.

#### Example

In the example below, I use the fact that the `a` and `input` are siblings (both children of the same `div`) to consider them "linked".

There are many variations of this concept; below is shown just one of them.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <input value="Input 1" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings('input').show();
});

$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings('a').show();
});
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bbWdS/)

Comment: There's no need for them to have `id` values and keeping a lot of unique ID values on a page gets to be a maintenance pain. They can be related structurally.

Comment: @T.J.: If you have "a lot" of elements, it seems likely that they are generated programmatically.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, but even if you do, relating them structurally may still be simpler.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: How would you related them structurally?

Comment: @T.J.: Possibly. I'll add a section to my answer to cover this.

Comment: @Tomaloak: +1, thanks. Having said that, I don't like either approach that much.

Comment: @Tomalak: As the code grew larger (and it will continue to grow!) I have parsed my code into *modules*, which accepts some representations of my "meta-object" and return different representations. The signatures become very messy, and the code is hard to maintain. I'm convinced there is a way to do things in a simply manner, since conceptually it's quite simple. Your approaches don't help in communication between the modules.

Comment: @Randomblue: I don't understand how the one affects the other. If you really cannot add an `id` attribute to your DOM elements or group them in the DOM, then your framework is prohibiting you from doing pretty much anything, which seems rather odd. Good luck!